# Why DOM has object oriented structure when JS is not?

Tags: javascript, dom

In DOM (JS rappresentation of HTML parsed file) we have this structure(where **<** is for "**inherited**"):

```
   Object(JS object) < Node < Element < HTMLElment < HTMLBodyElement, HTMLDivElement, etc..
   Object(JS object) < Node < DOcument < HTMLDocument
   ...
```

All these nodes are called interfaces (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) in every documentation I have checked.

I don't understand how is this possible in JS (not object-oriented, no interfaces, etc)? I have a background in C++, so maybe I am confusing DOM "object-oriented" structure with a real one. Any clarification?

Comment: The DOM does not (formally) have anything to do with JavaScript. They are completely separate specifications.

Comment: ... furthermore, check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) for the inheritance model of JS.

Comment: @Keryanie ... 1/2 ... The OP might also read about the criteria which makes/qualifies a PL an/as OO language before stating that _"JS is not"_ OO. To make it short ... In addition of having entities/objects which feature properties and methods it boils down to _**Encapsulation**_, _**Polymorphism**_ and _**Inheritance**_. All 3 criteria are equally important. _JavaScript_ covers all of them very well and in a charming way (but in the end also not that unique as some might think).

Comment: @Keryanie ... 2/2 ... _**Encapsulation**_ is achieved by _closures_ which keep local scope _"alive"_ / accessible. JS features _**Polymorphism**_ at many levels e.g. by overloaded operators (_Ad hoc polymorphism_), by generic functions (_Parametric polymorphism_), by late binding / dynamic dispatch (_Subtyping_). _**Inheritance**_ gets covered by a _delegation automatism_ that operates an object's _prototype chain_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand how is this possible in JS (not object-oriented, no interfaces, etc)?

There's no problem modelling the DOM's structure in JavaScript. JavaScript is **very** object-oriented, including supporting inheritance. JavaScript uses [prototypical inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming). Example:

```js
// Create an object with a method
const base = {
    baseMethod() {
        console.log("baseMethod");
    }
};

// Create an object using `base` as its prototype,
// perhaps add a property to it
const sub = Object.assign(Object.create(base), {
    subMethod() {
        console.log("subMethod");
    }
});

// Sub inherits `base`'s properties
sub.baseMethod(); // "baseMethod"

// And has its own
sub.subMethod();  // "subMethod"
```

JavaScript also overlays something on top of prototypical inheritance that **seems** rather `class`-like (it isn't, it's still prototypical, but it's more comfortable for people coming from class-based languages). For instance, here's a three-layer inheritance model (rather like `Node` < `Element` < `HTMLElement`) using `class` syntax (but again, we could do all of this without `class` syntax, too):

```js
class Base {
    baseMethod() {
        console.log("baseMethod");
    }
}

class Sub extends Base {
    subMethod() {
        console.log("subMethod");
    }
}

class SubSub extends Sub {
    subSubMethod() {
        console.log("subSubMethod");
    }
}

const x = new SubSub();
x.baseMethod();                     // "baseMethod"
x.subMethod();                      // "subMethod"
x.subSubMethod();                   // "subSubMethod"
console.log(x instanceof Base);     // true
console.log(x instanceof Sub);      // true
console.log(x instanceof SubSub);   // true
console.log(x instanceof Date);     // false (just to show it's not always true ;-) )
```

*(The `Object` base of that structure is implicit.)*